# How to hide the Cancel button on the 'myaccount-order' page, follow the payment-gateway?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, payment-gateway

How to hide the Cancel button on the page 'myaccount-order' when 'Payment Mothod Title' is 'Npay'?

Comment: move this file `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\myaccount\my-orders.php' to your theme folder and check in this file

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hook to remove the "Cancel" button.
"woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions"

```
add_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'remove_my_cancel_button', 10, 2);
function remove_my_cancel_button($actions, $order){
    unset($actions['cancel']);
    return $actions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
/* You can remove any actions available on the Actions column of the My account > Orders section. Here is the example code to remove the “Cancel” button – */

add_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'remove_myaccount_orders_cancel_btn', 10, 2);
function remove_myaccount_orders_cancel_btn( $actions, $order ){
    unset($actions['cancel']); 
    return $actions;
}
```